# Automatic renewal of prices of items in form based to a table column

Tags: forms

```
 I have a table with items in one column and price in another column. In the proof of purchase form, when I choose an item, I press Enter, I go to the next field and write the quantity, and in the next Enter, multiplication is automatically done with the price of the item and the total amount is displayed in the corresponding field.
  The problem is that I changed the prices in many items, but there was no automatic update in the form. I will have to make the same clicks with Enter, so that the new price is taken and thus the total amount is renewed again.
  What can I do about it? Thanks in advance.
```

I'm trying in a form, to automatically update the monetary values that a field takes from a table, so that the general monetary total changes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.